# how lucene handles sortfield with comparator if sortfield is ""

Tags: java, sorting, lucene, distance

i dont understand how sort by distance has been achieved using below mentioned code.

Please explain me...how lucene handles sortfield if sortfield is ""?

```
   DistanceQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new DistanceQueryBuilder(latitude, longitude, radius, "lat", "lon", CartesianTierPlotter.DEFALT_FIELD_PREFIX, true);
   DistanceFieldComparatorSource distComp = new DistanceFieldComparatorSource(queryBuilder.getDistanceFilter());
   Sort distSort = new Sort(new SortField("", distComp,false));
```

EDIT1:

```
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, queryBuilder.getFilter(), 20,distSort);
```

PS: i am using lucene 3.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SortField` essentially is just going to pass the field name along to the Comparator, and let it handle getting the correct values and doing the comparison.  As such, the `DistanceFieldComparatorSource` just tosses the field name out anyway.  This makes a measure of sense, since that comparator needs to accesses two fields (`lat` and `lon` in this case) to perform its comparison, rather than just one.

Instead, the `DistanceFilter` wraps up the field names the comparator needs to access, as well as some other attendant data.

Comment: Thanks @femtoRgon . could pls clarify more on DistanceFilter? what are the data it holds?

Comment: I'd recommend looking to the source code of [`LatLongDistanceFilter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-spatial/3.0.2/org/apache/lucene/spatial/tier/LatLongDistanceFilter.java#LatLongDistanceFilter) if you need more details on it's implementation.